# Swift closure capture list with nil values

Tags: swift, closures, automatic-ref-counting, block

I am capturing a delegate reference that is eventually set to some value, but initially is nil. However, the captured reference stays nil, even if the delegate is set.

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(2)) { [weak delegate] in
    delegate?.something() // delegate is nil
}

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(2)) { [weak self] in
    self?.delegate?.something() // delegate is not nil
}
```

What is going on here?

Comment: I don't understand why every one downvoting this question. nothing wrong in it.

Comment: Hm yeah true, strange.. I wish there was a field where people have to enter the reason for downvoting.

Answer (score 3):

Using a caputure list like `[weak delegate] in` will *copy* the value of the delegate at the very moment the closure is being initialized. Therefore, when the delegate is `nil` at that very instant, if will stay `nil` inside the closure, no matter if you modify `self.delegate` at some later time. This also holds true for `[weak self]`, with the little exception that `self` typically does not change in Swift.

Check this example:

```
class Delegate {

}

class A {
    var delegate:Delegate?

    func foo() {
        print ("in foo ---------------------")
        delegate = nil
        print ("delegate before: \(delegate)")  // prints: "nil"
        var closure = { print ("in closure: \(self.delegate)")}
        closure()   // prints: "in closure: nil"
        delegate = Delegate()
        print ("delegate after: \(delegate)") // prints "Optional(SwiftPlayground.Delegate)"
        closure() // prints "in closure: Optional(SwiftPlayground.Delegate)"
    }
    func bar() {
        print ("in bar ---------------------")
        delegate = nil  // prints "nil"
        print ("delegate before: \(delegate)")
        var closure = { [weak delegate] in print ("in closure: \(delegate)")}
        closure() // prints: "in closure: nil"
        delegate = Delegate()   // prints "Optional(SwiftPlayground.Delegate)"
        print ("delegate after: \(delegate)")
        closure() // prints "nil"
    }
}

let a = A()
a.foo()
a.bar()
```

Here, the very last `closure()` call in `func bar` will print `nil`, because `delegate` was `nil` at the time the `closure` was initialized.

Comment: Thank you sir. Yes, however I was kind of expecting that what is being copied at the time of the closure initialisation is a pointer to an optional-struct of some sort, and that if the optional becomes non-nil, the pointer would reflect that. But looks like there's nothing at runtime, theres either a pointer to delegate, or theres a 0x0 or whatever value in that pointer indicating nil. it's copied as you say. thanks for taking the time to write the example!

Comment: You simply can skip the capture list, and everything should work fine.